# How can I convert these Blender video settings to ffmpeg please?

Tags: ffmpeg, command, blender

Whenever I use the ffmpeg commands, the video is larger and the seeking/keyframe inteval is not the same as the video rendered from Blender. How can I convert the following Blender settings to ffmpeg please?

Blender Settings:

- Frame rate: 30
- Codec: h.264
- Output .mp4
- Keyframe interval: 1
- Output quality: Medium
- Encoding speed: Good

Here's my current command however the seeking and file size is different:
`ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i %04d.jpg -g 1 -vcodec libx264 video.mp4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -i %04d.jpg -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 -x264-params keyint=30:scenecut=0 -preset veryslow video.mp4
```

Explanation:

`-r 30` befor input pictures will say ffmpeg to use 30 pictures per second

`-vcodec libx264` will let ffmpeg encode in plain old H.264

`-crf 25` will let the encoder decide on the bitrate for a medium quality (lower it for better quality / higher file size, increase it for worse quality / lower file size. Need to find your right setting there through testing)

`-x264-params keyint=30:scenecut=0` will tell the x264 encoder to set a keyframe every 30s frames (here 1s) and to disable scene detection. Be aware that this increases the file size a lot, you should not use a keyframe every second, except for livestreaming. Modern video encoders like AV1 will at most times set a keyframe every 10-20s based on scene detection.

`-preset veryslow` will use the best libx264 preset available to make the file as small as possible with H.264 (however needs more time to encode). If you want a faster encode but a larger file set it to `slow`.

Some general opinions from me:

If you don't need compatibility to very old devices rather encode with libx265 or 2-pass libvpx-vp9. This will save you a lot of space without quality loss. libx265 slow is even faster then libx264 veryslow for me.